# SELECT by value of dynamically generated field value

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm working with a table that includes various items of stock on a small, custom built ecommerce site. My client has requested a number of filters, including price range.

Easy enough except they also require user-dependent pricing, based on various factors in the user's account, so the price is calculated in the query.

The ideal SQL is something like this:

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.*,
    IF(s.value_a <= 0.5, s.price*1.1*0.80, s.price*1.5*0.80) AS total_price 
FROM stock s
WHERE
    (total_price >= :minimum_price_filter AND total_price <= :maximum_price_filter)
    AND (s.value_b='X' OR s.value_b='Y')
ORDER BY total_price ASC, s.value_a, s.value_b LIMIT 0,25
```

(`1.1*0.80` and `1.5*0.80` are the four user-dependent values.)

Obviously that `SELECT` calculation works fine, as does the `ORDER`, and the `WHERE` for the other values in the table: but now adding in this price filter doesn't work as that price field (`total_price`) and its value is dynamically generated in the query.

Any tips or hints as to how adding that price range filter to the `WHERE` clause might actually be possible?

`WHERE (total_price >= :minimum_price_filter AND total_price <= :maximum_price_filter)`

If it makes any different to how the problem is approached, I'm working in PHP and PDO.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.*, 
    IF(s.value_a <= 0.5, s.price*1.1*0.80, s.price*1.5*0.80) AS total_price 
FROM 
    stock s 
WHERE 
    s.value_b='X' 
    OR s.value_b='Y'
HAVING
    total_price <= :maximum_price_filter
    AND total_price >= :minimum_price_filter
ORDER BY 
    total_price ASC, 
    s.value_a, s.value_b 
LIMIT 
    0,25
```

This query should do the job.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I will make sure I read up on `HAVING`. Much appreciated.